# Jade: changes to mixin syntax in v 1.0.x?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I upgraded Jade `0.34.1` from to `1.0.2` . I used to pass objects to mixins like below,

```
mixin testmix(itm)
    p #{itm.lbl}

dat = {lbl: 'Test me'}
+testmix(dat)
```

it doesn't work anymore, giving error.

```
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lbl' of undefined
```

this works though,

```
mixin testmix(itm)
    p #{itm.lbl}

+testmix({lbl: 'Test me'})
```

I really needs to assign variables as in the first option as I define many variables in a separate file. What is changed, and how to make it work?

the [changelog](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/History.md) mainly talks about changes to `attributes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
dat = {lbl: 'Test me'}
```

to

```
- dat = {lbl: 'Test me'}
```

or

```
- var dat = {lbl: 'Test me'}
```

solved for me